# Invalid Compare password using hash in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and if I try to change password it doesn't work !

**change password model**

```
public function compare_passwords(){
            $salt = hash('sha256',$this->user . HASH . $this->vars['old_password']);

    //$salt = sha1(sha1(HASH).$this->vars['old_password'].sha1(HASH));
    return ($_SESSION['pass'] == $salt);
}

public function update_password(){
    $salt = hash('sha256',$this->user . HASH . $this->password);
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE bg_user SET passwd = :pass WHERE user_id = :user');
    return $stmt->execute(array(':user' => $_SESSION['name'], ':pass' => $salt));
}
```

**Registration model**

```
public function create_account(){
    $salt = hash('sha256',$this->user . HASH . $this->password);
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO bg_user (user_id, passwd, email, activated, secret_question, secret_answer,ip) VALUES (:user, :pass, :email, :status, :secret_question, :secret_answer,:ip)');
    return $stmt->execute(array(':user' => $this->user, ':pass' => $salt,':email' => $this->email, ':status' => 1,':secret_question' => $this->secret_question,':secret_answer' => $this->secret_answer,':ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
}
```

**Login model**

```
public function login_user(){       
    $salt = hash('sha256',$this->user . HASH . $this->password);
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT user_code, user_id, passwd FROM bg_user WHERE user_id = :user AND passwd = :pass');
    $stmt->execute(array(':user' => $this->vars['user'], ':pass' => $salt));
    $info = $stmt->fetch();
    if($info){
        $_SESSION['usercode'] = $info['user_code'];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $info['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $info['passwd'];
        return true;
    }   
    return false;
}
```

registration and login works perfect !

Comment: The way that `compare_passwords` generates the password looks different to the others.

Comment: i tried this but nothing : $salt = hash('sha256',$this->user . HASH . $this->vars['old_password']);

Comment: Where does `$this->vars['old_password']` get set?

Comment: If you're recieving data from `POST` method you can use the native `codeigniter` class helper, i'd recommend you read this https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is possible to convert that to CI?

```
 $pseudo = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(33));
 $password_sha256 = strtoupper(hash("sha256",$username_register.$pseudo.$password_register));
 $security_code_sha256 = strtoupper(hash("sha256",$username_register.$pseudo.$security_code));
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `Average_db_auth`.`bg_user` (user_id, email, passwd, ip, salt, security_code) VALUES ('$username_register', '$email_register', '$password_sha256', '$ip', '$pseudo', '$security_code_sha256')";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
```